# how to set name space or use model in laravel by constant declared in helper file

Tags: php, laravel, model, constants

I have a laravel code

I have this constant  (ADMINMODELPATH), I declare it in helper file.

I want to use it like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbjzH.png

I try this:

```
use ${ADMINMODELPATH}\Admin;
```

and this :

```
use ADMINMODELPATH\Admin;
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include all your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: "I want to use it like this" - what does that mean? Anything not working with the second attempt?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to set name's namespace with variables or constants. You can't set it with `eval('namespace '.$var)` function also. PHP doesn't accept to set namespaces after a variable, a function or etc. You must set firstly them. These are strict rules of PHP.

You can look for defining syntax of namespaces here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

Comment: can i use model like:  use ADMINMODELPATH\Admin;